# Google Calendar not have attachments when creating event from .ics file

Tags: calendar, gmail, icalendar

I am creating calendar event by sending ics file through email. Ics file contains attachments like below.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Test
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20220325T080000Z
DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20220325T100000Z
UID:e5437cc3-0145-457f-a244-37cce703dda0
ATTACH;ENCODING=BASE64;VALUE=BINARY;X-FILENAME=sample.pdf:<base64_data>
LOCATION:London\, UK
ORGANIZER;CN="CN TEXT";ROLE="ROLE ADMIN":MAILTO:<mail_to>
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

When adding to calendar, Outlook Calendar works fine but the event on Google Calendar does not have the attachments.

I also tried but still

```
ATTACH;FILENAME="sample.pdf";FMTTYPE=application/pdf:https://drive.google.com/<file>
```

Thank you for any help